# how to validate user inputs in react using setState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form. In the form I getting brandName, supplierName, and date of expiry from the user.
I am usinf TextField from mui library and submit button.
I want to disable submit button on empty form fields and enable it when user filled all the inputs
here is my code for declaring useStates

```
       const[brandName, setBrandName] = useState("");
       const[supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState("");
       const[expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState(null);
       const[brandNameError, setBrandNameError] = useState(false);
       const[supplierNameError, setSupplierNameError] = useState(false);
       const[expiryDateError, setExpiryDateError] = useState(false);

       const[submitButton, setSubmitButton] = useState(true);
```

and here is all function which i used to validate my inputs

```
       // checking brandName Error
        const brandNameValidateOnBlur = ()=>{
          if(brandName === ""){
            setBrandNameError(true);
          }
       }

       // checking supplier name error
       const supplierNameValidateOnBlur = ()=>{
        if(supplierName === ""){
            setSupplierNameError(true);
        }
       }
       // checking expiry date
       const expiryDateValidateOnBlur = ()=>{
        if(expiryDate === ""){
            setExpiryDateError(true);
        }
       }
 
        // now checking all inputs again if all inputs are good then
        // button should be enabled 

        const checkAllInputs = ()=>{
            if(brandName !== "" && supplierName !== "" && expiryDate !== ""){
                setSubmitButton(false);
            }else{
                setSubmitButton(true);
            }
        }
```

and here is the rest of code

```
       <TextField  fullWidth id="productName" label="Product Name" 
        value={brandName.toLowerCase()} variant="outlined" 
      onChange={(data)=>{setBrandName(data.target.value.toUpperCase());checkAllInputs()}}
      onBlur={brandNameValidateOnBlur}
      onFocus={()=>setBrandNameError(false)}
      error={brandNameError}
      helperText = {brandNameError ? "Enter Brand Name" : ""}
      />
      <TextField id="supplierName"  
      label="Supplier Name" 
      value={supplierName.toLowerCase()} variant="outlined"
      onBlur={supplierNameValidateOnBlur}
      onFocus={()=>setSupplierNameError(false)}
      error={supplierNameError}
      helperText={supplierNameError ? "Enter Supplier Name " : ""}
      onChange={(data)=>{setSupplierName(data.target.value.toUpperCase());checkAllInputs()}} />
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Date Expiry"
          inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
          value={expiryDate}
          onBlur={expiryDateValidateOnBlur}
          onFocus={()=>setExpiryDateError(false)}
          error={expiryDateError}
          helperText={expiryDateError ? "Enter Expiry Date ": ""}
          onChange={(selectedDate)=>
          {setExpiryDate(selectedDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));checkAllInputs()}}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
     </LocalizationProvider>
      <Button type='button' variant='contained' id="submitButton" disabled={submitButton}
      style={{backgroundColor:'orangered'}} onClick={addData}>Add Data</Button>
```

now problem is when i enter a single word my useState is updated but my checkAllInputs not working as i want to be like if i enter a word my checkAllInputs method runs before setting of state as i enter second entry then it works like I want to be so i did not know what i am doing wrong

I TRY useEffect hook like that

```
       useEffect(()=>{
        checkAllInputs();
       },[brandName, supplierName, expiryDate]);
```

its working fine as i accepted but I read that it should be a expensive to use useEffect

and an other approach which i use

```
         const checkAllInputsWithDom = ()=>{
         let brandNameEntry = document.getElementById("brandName").value;
         let supplierNameEntry = document.getElementById("supplierName").value;
         let expiryDateEntry = document.getElementById("expiryDate").value;
         if(brandNameEntry !=="" && supplierNameEntry !== ""  && expiryDateEntry !== ""){
            setSubmitButton(false);
         }else{
            setSubmitButton(true);
         }
      }
```

it is working out of box but I thing in react this is against react principles to direct manipulate
dome elements  can I do it with out using useeffect hook like only with my metohd and one more thing
this did not set expiryDate error in date field

Comment: Minor comment here but your onBlur function  is missspelled you currently have onBulr.

Comment: thanks for letting know it misspelled i correct it

Comment: pls use prettier or format code by yourself. It so hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're keeping the input values in state, you don't need another variable storing the button state as well. You can calculate it at render time. (Read more about avoiding redundant state [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state).)

You could do something like this:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const[brandName, setBrandName] = useState("");
  const[supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState("");
  const[expiryDate, setExpiryDate] = useState("");

  const disabled = brandName.length === 0 && supplierName.length === 0 && expiryDate.length === 0

  return (
    <>
      <input value={brandName} onChange={(e) => setBrandName(e.target.value)}/>
      <input value={supplierName} onChange={(e) => setSupplierName(e.target.value)}/>
      <input value={expiryDate} onChange={(e) => setExpiryDate(e.target.value)}/>
      <button disabled={disabled}>Button</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: as i tried but it gives me this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Comment: That's because you're initializing the state value with `null`. If that's required for your input, the check would then have to be `!== null` instead of `.length === 0`. However, if it's an input that takes text values, you're better off initializing it with `""` (empty string).

Comment: I change it to "" but as i enter a word in any input it enables the button but i want to when all input fields are filled then button should be enabled

Comment: Then change it to `brandName.length === 0 || supplierName.length === 0 || expiryDate.length === 0`

Comment: thanks dear it works but tell me it is ok to use useEffect hook ? and we can use to get value like with id from direct from the dom?

Comment: In this case `useEffect` is not needed, so I would avoid it. `useEffect` is used to [escape the normal flow of React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/escape-hatches#you-might-not-need-an-effect). As for selecting elements by id, that is never recommended in React. Whenever you need to reference a specific element, you can use the `useRef` [hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef), but you should use it sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

here is the [link for codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dew-3nllgf?file=/src/App.js) I have a suggestion for you to refactor this 6 use States with just one useState as an object having all the values like the following:

```
  const initialValues = {
  brandName: "",
  supplierName: "",
  expiryDate: "",
  brandNameError: "",
  supplierNameError: "",
  expiryDateError: ""
};
```

and then update it with a generic `handleInputChange` like below:

```
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    //const name = e.target.name
    //const value = e.target.value
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value
    });
    let isEmpty = Object.values(values).some((x) => x === "");
    console.log(isEmpty);
    setIsDisabled(isEmpty);
  };
```

**FOR YOUR SOLUTION**

You will have to just check all the values and just create a boolean with isDisabled so when all of those values are empty then it will only set to false.

I have created a code snippet for you, it needs some improvement but it will serve your purpose. Link already at the top and [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-dew-3nllgf?file=/src/App.js) as well

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Eduardo Motta de Moraes
I used this for making my button enabled after all inputs validate

```
const disabled= brandName.length === 0 || supplierName.length === 0 || expiryDate.length === 0;
```

this solve my problem
thanks for Eduardo Motta de Moraes  for this